# Python DJANGO Error IndexError at / list index out of range

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I am new to python. Trying to create a simple application using django. I am facing the index out of range exception with this line "ndim = mobjs[0].ndim". Any help would be highly appreciated

Error

```
\File "/home/anthra/server_movierecsys/books_recsys_app/views.py", line 66, in home
ndim = mobjs[0].ndim
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
context={}
if request.method == 'POST':
    post_data = request.POST
    data = {}
    data = post_data.get('data', None)
    if data:
        return redirect('%s?%s' % (reverse('books_recsys_app.views.home'),
                            urllib.urlencode({'q': data})))
elif request.method == 'GET':
    get_data = request.GET
    data = get_data.get('q',None)
    titles = cache.get('titles')
    if titles==None:
        print ('load data...')
        texts = []
        mobjs = MovieData.objects.all()
        ndim = mobjs[0].ndim
        matr = np.empty([1,ndim])

    else:
        print ('loaded',str(len(titles)))
```

Comment: Take a look at what the queryset `mobjs` is set to after the db query. You'll find that it is empty. Are you sure that there are records in the database for that model?

Comment: That's because `MovieData.objects.all()` returns an empty `QuerySet` (`[]`). Later, when you try to access the first element, it fails.

Comment: Add at least one `MovieData` and you should be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    mobjs = MovieData.objects.all().first()
    if mobjs:
        ndim = mobjs[0].ndim
        matr = np.empty([1,ndim])
    else:
        print('there is no MovieData')
```

Comment: It probably not help if queryset will be empty

Comment: the empty queryset first() will return None,whta's the problem?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I made mistake)

Comment: Queryset was empty

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use **try: except:** statement and except Error. You can write your own Exception or use some of biuld ones:[Python Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Something like that:

```
try:
    mobjs = MovieData.objects.all()
    ndim = mobjs[0].ndim
    matr = np.empty([1,ndim])
except Exception as e: 
    print(e)
```

Hope it's working ;P